# How can I reset an instance attribute?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using kivy to generate a scrollview with buttons inside each labeled by a number when a button is clicked. I also have another button that clears the buttons from the scrollview but it keeps the numbers and doesn't reset to 0.

My python code:

```
class GetLinksButton(Button):

    link_number = 1

    def get_links(self):
        for i in xrange(3):
            link_button = LinkButton(
                text='link number ' + str(self.link_number)
            )
            self.link_number += 1
            self.links_grid.add_widget(link_button)


class LinkButton(Button):
    pass

class Clearlinkbuttons(Button):
    def clear_links(self):
        self.links_grid.clear_widgets()
        GetLinksButton.link_number = 1
```

My kivy code:

```
<RightArea@GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    size_hint_x: 0.3
    spacing: '10dp'

    ScrollView:
        LinksGrid:
            id: links_grid

    BoxLayout:
        cols: 1
        rows: 2
        GetLinksButton:
            links_grid: links_grid
        Clearlinkbuttons:
            links_grid: links_grid


<LinksGrid@GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    spacing: '5dp'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height


<GetLinksButton>:
    size_hint_y: 0.1
    text: 'get links'
    on_press: self.get_links()

<Clearlinkbuttons>:
    size_hint_y: 0.1
    text: 'clear links'
    on_press: self.clear_links()

<LinkButton>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '80dp'
```

My App after I've pressed the the get links and clear links buttons a few times:

[image: test_app]

The scrollview is at the top.

I've also tried:

```
class Clearlinkbuttons(Button):
    def clear_links(self):
        self.links_grid.clear_widgets()
        self.links_grid.link_number = 1
```

Comment: Please read up on [class and instance variables](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) and [Kivy properties](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#comparison-python-vs-kivy)

Comment: The problem is, in your `clear_links` method, you are setting the attribute of the *class* `GetLinksButton`, not an instance.

Comment: @zondo which may be what he wants (counting the number of all links), but in `get_links`, `self.link_number += 1` creates an _instance_ variable, which gets incremented. It gets initialized with the _class_ variable, hence no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class `GetLinksButton`, replace every occurence of `self.link_number` with `GetLinksButton.link_number`.

When you have a static variable (`link_number`), and call it with object instance (`self`) instead of the class(`GetLinksButton`), the variable is copied to an object that uses it.